# Page column meaning in Google Analytics

Tags: universal-analytics

Why "Page" value differs between "Behavior->Site Content->All Pages" 
and "Behavior->Events->Pages"?

In "Behavior->Site Content->All Pages" I see page name what I specified for page view hit (as expected) but
in "Behavior->Events->Pages" I see page URL. In both cases column name is "Page".

Answer (score 1):

The "All Pages" lists all the pages on your site that were visited, including any relevant statistics. The Events Pages lists pages on your site that fired events, including any relevant statistics.

Comment: +1 for explaining difference between those views. But the question is - why in one place I see page field (I explicitly setting up page field value for "page view" tracking) but in other place I see ugly URL.

Comment: Because you probably do not send your beautified page value with the event tracking as well (it does not take the value from the page view field, you need to use a configuration object as parameter to your event tracking call and fill the value for "page" there).